# jquery - using .each() once for each product to insert new price

Tags: jquery, html, each

Hi I'm having trouble with .each() firing once for each element it's looking at.

So on an ecommerce site theres a page with a list of products, each product has a containing div **#productListings .productListItem** and inside that div there is some data including a price **.itemPrice**.

I'm trying to get it to look in each products containing div, take the price, divide it by 20% and show the new price just underneath:

```
$( "#productListings .productListItem" ).each(function() {
  var PLPpriceStripped = ($('.itemPrices .pri', this).text()).replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
  var PLPdiscount = (PLPpriceStripped/100)*20;
  var PLPnewPrice = PLPpriceStripped-PLPdiscount;

  $('<div class="nowPrice">' + 'Discounted Price*: £' + PLPnewPrice + '</div>').insertAfter('.itemPrice', this);
});
```

When I run this it returns £0 as the value (Which means my code isn't working as intended) but also duplicates this once for every product on the page under every product in the page.

I've obviously not got a 100% grip with .each() but also it's not returning the correct prices under each product either.

Any help please?

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1bqh2f90/7/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( "#productListings .productListItem" ).each(function() {
    var PLPpriceStripped = ($('.itemPrices .pri', this).text()).replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
    var PLPdiscount = (PLPpriceStripped/100)*20;
    var PLPnewPrice = PLPpriceStripped-PLPdiscount;

    $('<div class="nowPrice">' + 'Discounted Price*: £' + PLPnewPrice + '</div>').insertAfter('.itemPrice', this);
  });

});
```

```css
#productListings {
  display:block;
  font-size:0;
}

#productListings .productListItem {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:1%;
  width:48%;
}

#productListings .productListItem img {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}

#productListings .productListItem .prices {
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
}

#productListings .productListItem .was {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-size:12px;
}

#productListings .productListItem .pri {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:12px;
}

.nowPrice {
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="productListings">
  <div class="productListItem">
    <img src="http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize/v2.2/layout03/images/img4.jpg" />
    <div class="productName">
      
    </div>
    <div class="itemPrices">
      <div class="was">Was £20</div> <div class="pri">Now £15</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="productListItem">
    <img src="http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize/v2.2/layout03/images/img4.jpg" />
    <div class="productName">
      
    </div>
    <div class="itemPrices">
      <div class="pri">Now £20</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="productListItem">
    <img src="http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize/v2.2/layout03/images/img4.jpg" />
    <div class="productName">
      
    </div>
    <div class="itemPrices">
      <div class="pri">Now £50</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="productListItem">
    <img src="http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize/v2.2/layout03/images/img4.jpg" />
    <div class="productName">
      
    </div>
    <div class="itemPrices">
      <div class="was">Was £50</div> <div class="pri">Now £30</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML code?

Comment: Add code snippet for better clarification...

Comment: As far as I can see [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) does not expect a second argument, so you're adding the content to a lot more than you want to. Use instead: `.insertAfter($('.itemPrice', this))`

Comment: Try to use `var PLPpriceStripped = $(this).find(".itemPrices.pri").text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');`

Comment: @ArunKumar, why would that change anything?

Comment: @trincot there might be space issue in selector and just giving another alternative

Comment: Add a full snippet so we can see...

Comment: Sorry I was hoping that was enough, obviously this is trying to work with a functioning ecommerce site but I'll try and set up a JSfiddle with the basics of the page layout and what I need.

Comment: Here's the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1bqh2f90/7/ added it to the original post thanks

Comment: I've added a Stack Snippet from the code in that fiddle. Note that you can do this yourself by clicking on the icon that has `<>` on it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks I'm sure I had done this before but couldnn't remember how.

Comment: @trincot Sorry I missed this, this worked thanks at making it only show once per product however I'm still returning £0 for very product instead of the **.pri** value minus 20%. Any help with that?

Comment: See my answer... Although I never got a £0  with the fiddle you provided.

Comment: Thanks @trincot that did help, I just saw it the next day. Thanks to all for the help :)

Comment: Please don't fix the code in the question. The answer doesn't make sense if the question doesn't contain the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. The class specification you have in the `insertAfter` argument lacks an "s". It should be `.itemPrices` instead of `.itemPrice`
2. [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) does not expect a second argument, so you're adding the content to a lot more than you want to. Use instead:

   ```
   .insertAfter($('.itemPrices', this))
   ```
3. The CSS class `nowPrice` is not enough to make the additional content visible, because a parent element has a CSS `font-size:0`, which is like "How can I make life difficult for myself!?". Anyway, with such a font size you don't see the additional content in your fiddle. The quickest solution is to specify a font size for the `nowPrice` CSS class

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j9nyhzs8/

And the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( "#productListings .productListItem" ).each(function() {
    var PLPpriceStripped = ($('.itemPrices .pri', this).text()).replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
    var PLPdiscount = (PLPpriceStripped/100)*20;
    var PLPnewPrice = PLPpriceStripped-PLPdiscount;

    $('<div class="nowPrice">' + 'Discounted Price*: £' + PLPnewPrice + '</div>').insertAfter($('.itemPrices', this));
  });

});
```

```css
#productListings {
  display:block;
  font-size:0;
}

#productListings .productListItem {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:1%;
  width:48%;
}

#productListings .productListItem img {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}

#productListings .productListItem .prices {
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
}

#productListings .productListItem .was {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-size:12px;
}

#productListings .productListItem .pri {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:12px;
}

.nowPrice {
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="productListings">
  <div class="productListItem">
    <img src="http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize/v2.2/layout03/images/img4.jpg" />
    <div class="productName">
      
    </div>
    <div class="itemPrices">
      <div class="was">Was £20</div> <div class="pri">Now £15</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="productListItem">
    <img src="http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize/v2.2/layout03/images/img4.jpg" />
    <div class="productName">
      
    </div>
    <div class="itemPrices">
      <div class="pri">Now £20</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="productListItem">
    <img src="http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize/v2.2/layout03/images/img4.jpg" />
    <div class="productName">
      
    </div>
    <div class="itemPrices">
      <div class="pri">Now £50</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="productListItem">
    <img src="http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize/v2.2/layout03/images/img4.jpg" />
    <div class="productName">
      
    </div>
    <div class="itemPrices">
      <div class="was">Was £50</div> <div class="pri">Now £30</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Sorry I work early shifts so had left before getting your reply, this did help the main thing I was missing was the **.insertAfter($('.itemPrice', this))**

However the issue with the prices was actually the opposite to what you thought, it was actually there wasn't mean to be the extra 's' in this var: **var PLPpriceStripped = ($('.itemPrices .pri', this).text()).replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');** so it wasn't performing this part and was why I was getting £0 values.

Comment: The last part I need to figure out is how I get the .00 pence decimals showing but thanks for helping getting the main issue sorted :)

Comment: @Chobbit, if the `s` was to be removed from `.itemPrices`, then don't forget to also adapt the HTML, as in your question the HTML specified `class="itemPrices"`. Maybe it was another typo in your question and fiddle then? NB: for showing decimals, look into the [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method.

Answer (score 0):

If your query selector works well, your should try `.append()` instead of `.insertAfter()`:

```
$( "#productListings .productListItem").each(function() {
  // ...

  var nowPrice = $('<div class="nowPrice">' + 'Discounted Price*: £' + PLPnewPrice + '</div>');

  $( this ).append(nowPrice);
});
```

Comment: `$( "#productListings")` will always be one element (id's need to be unique). So no need to iterate over that using the each loop. You also use the each loop in the wrong way. The OP selector was correct.

Comment: Sure, if you had investigated in the code, you would have noticed that this was a copy-paste-mistake. `each()` needs a function as an argument. But thanks at all.

Comment: I down voted because you posted an answer with incorrect syntax. It's a good idea to test your code before posting. Snippets works great for that. Because you edited your answer I removed my downvote.